# tidyr replace NA doesn't seem to work on date vectors

Tags: r, date, replace, tidyr, na

```
library(tidyr)
df <- tibble(col1 = as.Date(c(NA, "2019-01-01")))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 1
#>   col1      
#>   <date>    
#> 1 NA        
#> 2 2019-01-01
```

I'm working with the tibble above. I'd like to replace `NA` with the character string `Not Applicable`. But it doesn't work. Why? What should I do?

```
df %>% replace_na(list(col1 = "Not Applicable"))
#> Error in charToDate(x) : 
#>   character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Comment: You cannot mix column types, instead change the column to `character` before doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"Not applicable"` is `character` and we are trying to change the `NA` in the `Date` class with a `character`.  Some of the actions cannot be done as these are going to be different class output.  Instead, change the `class` beforehand and then do the `replace_na`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(col1 = as.character(col1)) %>% 
   replace_na(list(col1 = "Not Applicable"))
# A tibble: 2 x 1
#  col1          
#  <chr>         
#1 Not Applicable
#2 2019-01-01
```

---

Or place it in a structure that can hold multiple types e.g. `list`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(col1 = map(col1, ~ if(is.na(.x)) "Not Applicable" else .x))
```